# How to put "a href link" into a <div>?

Tags: html, image

```
<div id='machineanimation' style='float:right;background:none !important; margin-right:36px;'>
  <a href="onet.pl">
    <img src='./pix/foto0.png' alt='' />
  </a>
  <img src='./pix/foto1.png' alt='' />
  <img src='./pix/foto2.png' alt='' />

</div>
```

I saw some topics but I don’t understand how to do it. I want to click on photo then it will change my website to other but in  i have trouble how to do it

Comment: Care to explain more?

Comment: You just have a block of html. We have literally no idea what you're trying to do. It doesn't matter if you're a beginner, you still need to explain what you're having trouble with.

Comment: probably You have an error with href value, try
`<a href="http://onet.pl">`
but I'm not sure about it because you don't explain your question

Comment: Your link is likely broken. Otherwise, your code appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you want. It seems like you want an image to be a hyperlink. Your code should work, so your issue must lie in the href attribute, if the image is showing up. If the image is not showing up, try checking the src attribute. Try changing the href to google, just to test. I put together a fiddle to demonstrate your code working: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/)

```
<div id='machineanimation' style='float:right;background:none !important; margin-right:36px;'>
    <a href="onet.pl">
        <img src='https://www.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/new/icon/075-smiley-face-vector-art-free-download-l.png' alt='' />
    </a>
    <img src='./pix/foto1.png' alt='' />
    <img src='./pix/foto2.png' alt='' />
    <img src='./pix/foto3.png' alt='' />
    <img src='./pix/foto4.png' alt='' />
</div>
```

As you can see, all I did was modify the image source.

Because it works with a different image, the fault most-likely lies in the image src attribute. Check it to confirm it is correct.

**NOTE:**

Inline styling is not recommended.